# How do I prevent clicking background when I click the IMGUI button

Tags: webgl, imgui

How do I prevent clicking background when I click the IMGUI button
(e.g. I click the translate button and also click the background)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check whether ImGui wants to capture the mouse click using `ImGui::GetIO().WantCaptureMouse`. If it does then don't let the event propagate further.

```cpp
void Application::handleInput(InputEvent event) {

        // don't pass mouse and keyboard presses further if an ImGui widget is active
        auto& io = ImGui::GetIO();
        if (io.WantCaptureMouse || io.WantCaptureKeyboard) {
            return;
        }

        // ... event processing
    }
}
```

ImGui FAQ: [Q: How can I tell whether to dispatch mouse/keyboard to Dear ImGui or my application?](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#q-how-can-i-tell-whether-to-dispatch-mousekeyboard-to-dear-imgui-or-my-application)